# regexp R - extract string between commas

Tags: r, regex, data.table, gsub

Because my csv file is broken, I'm reading it into R using:

```
dataDT <- data.table::fread(".../test.csv", sep = NULL)
```

And it gives a dataset something like:

```
dataDT <- data.table("ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD" = c("1,10,some text... , some text,,20190801",
                                               "2,22,some text... , some text,,20190801",
                                               "3,30,some text... , some text,,20170601"))
dataDT
> dataDT
                       ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD
1: 1,10,some text... , some text,,20190801
2: 2,22,some text... , some text,,20190801
3: 3,30,some text... , some text,,20170601
```

Now, what I want is to **split the string in each row into 4 new columns**:

```
targetDT <- data.table(ColA = c(1,2,3), 
                       ColB = c(10,22,30), 
                       ColC = c("some text... , some text,", "some text... , some text,", "some text... , some text,"),
                       ColD = c("20190801","20190801",'20170601'))
targetDT
> targetDT
   ColA ColB                      ColC     ColD
1:    1   10 some text... , some text, 20190801
2:    2   22 some text... , some text, 20190801
3:    3   30 some text... , some text, 20170601
```

The logic would be:

- ColA has the string before 1st comma;
- ColB has everything between 1st and 2nd comma;
- ColD has the string after the last comma;
- ColC has the string in the middle part (it might contain additional commas).

How to achieve the logic above?

Edit_1:

Sensitive data, sorry I can't provide the exact data. It looks like:

```
        ID,Code1,Project_Name,Report_Date
1:     123123,1, A & B,20100101
2:     1413,2, C, D and E,20120101
3: 53163,333, F, G,20140303
4: 23453,44,This is a name,20160801
5: 12645,555,5th test, to continue,20190501
```

So, everything before the 1st comma is definitely numbers, and so is everything between 1st and 2nd comma. Everything after last comma is definitely a date-like 8 digits number. The middle part can contain multiple commas but no quotes (Which I guess is the reason why fread treats comma as delimiters).

Comment: Please show some exact data.  `some text` may not be specific enough for someone to help you.

Comment: If you could logically split the data at the commas, then `fread` would have read it in the first place. If it couldn't, then it's an indicator that you have commas in the middle of unquoted strings. If you could define a rule to split those fields **other than the comma* (or remove those specific commas), then you'll have it. Check out for patterns in the data that you can use to achieve that

Comment: Each column data can be put into numbered arrays. Later each array element in a sequence can be used to create a row. Use a global type regex call to get each column array. `(?:(?:^|,)\s*)(?:"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"|'([^'\\]*(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*)'|([^,]*))(?:\s*(?:(?=,)|$))` Do this in a loop, each match is a new element and is the joining of group 1 and group 2 and group 3. See it here https://regex101.com/r/6uSkJI/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using stringr

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

dataDT <- data.table(data = c("1,10,some text... , some text,,20190801",
                               "2,22,some text... , some text,,20190801",
                               "3,30,some text... , some text,,20170601"))

dataDT <- dataDT %>% 
    mutate(
        ColA = str_extract(data, "^[^,]*(?=,)"),
        ColB = str_extract(data, "(?<=,)[^,]*(?=,)"),
        ColD = str_extract(data, "(?<=,)[^,]*$"),
        ColC = str_sub(data, nchar(ColA)+nchar(ColB)+3, nchar(data)-nchar(ColD)-1)
    ) %>% 
    select(ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD)

dataDT
#>   ColA ColB                      ColC     ColD
#> 1    1   10 some text... , some text, 20190801
#> 2    2   22 some text... , some text, 20190801
#> 3    3   30 some text... , some text, 20170601
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Loved this! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `regex` pattern that will allow you to substitute comma characters that are adjacent to the lead two and terminal numeric values and separate them from each other and the surrounding text with spaces. It might be safer to use a non-space character for separation since my next step would be to read thes "lines" with one of the `read.*` functions or perhaps `fread` again. Perhaps using "|" as a separator?

```
sub("(\\d+)[,](\\d+)[,](.+)[,](\\d+)$", 
    "\\1 \\2 '\\3' \\4", 
    dataDT$"ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD" )

[1] "1 10 'some text... , some text,' 20190801" "2 22 'some text... , some text,' 20190801"
[3] "3 30 'some text... , some text,' 20170601"
```

The parentheses in the pattern are used to create "capture classes" and in each case I have "captured" an arbitrary number of digits or decimal separators with the "\d+" pattern. I also surrounded the text (captured with ".+") with single quotes on the substitution pattern so the "interior spaces" in the third column-want-to-be would not be read as separators. The `"\\1"`, `"\\2"`, etc, are references back to the captured characters in each of the capture classes, ordered in sequence of their appearances in the pattern. See `?regex`. However, the single quotes would not be needed if you used a different separator.

Here's a test using "|" as a `sep`.

```
fread(text =sub("(\\d+)[,](\\d+)[,](.+)[,](\\d+)", "\\1|\\2|'\\3'|\\4", dataDT$"ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD" ) ,sep="|")
   V1 V2                          V3       V4
1:  1 10 'some text... , some text,' 20190801
2:  2 22 'some text... , some text,' 20190801
3:  3 30 'some text... , some text,' 20170601
```

Note: If your numeric values have commas or have leading or trailing currency, you need to change your example since using `"\\d"` to capture numeric groups of characters will no longer succeed.

Comment: Answers like this, with full explanation of the whys and hows, are what keeps me coming back again and again to SO. Thank you @42!

Answer (score 0):

The answers posted so far suggest solutions using regular expressions.

Alternatively, the *positions* of the columns can be considered. As the OP has pointed out

> - ColA has the string before 1st comma;
> - ColB has everything between 1st    and 2nd comma;
> - ColD has the string after the last comma;
> - ColC has the    string in the middle part (it might contain additional commas).

The idea is to read the file using `fread()` with `sep = ","` as usual which results in misaligned dataset. After reshaping to long format, the first, second, and last columns as well as the intermediate columns can be identified *per row*. These entries can given the respective column name. During the final reshape to wide format the intermediate columns are collapsed into `ColC`.

```
library(data.table)
# read file
DT <- fread("
1,10,some text...  some text,,20190801
2,22,some text... , some text,,20190801
3,30,some text... ,, some text,,20170601"
            , sep = ","
            , fill = TRUE
            , header = FALSE
            , strip.white = FALSE)
```

Note that the sample dataset has been modified by inserting additional comma to have a more realistic test case.

The result of the read operation is a misaligned and ragged dataset:

```
DT
```

> ```
>    V1 V2                      V3         V4         V5       V6       V7
> 1:  1 10 some text...  some text              20190801       NA       NA
> 2:  2 22           some text...   some text            20190801       NA
> 3:  3 30           some text...              some text       NA 20170601
> ```

```
cols <- c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD")
# reshape from wide to long format
long <- melt(DT[, rn := .I], "rn", na.rm = TRUE)
# create lookup table to rename column names  
lut <- long[, .(variable, col = rep(cols, c(1L, 1L, .N - 3, 1L))), by = rn]
# rename columns by an update join
long[lut,  on = .(rn, variable), variable := col][]
# reshape and collapse 
dcast(long, rn ~ variable, paste, collapse = ",")
```

> ```
>    ColA ColB                      ColC     ColD
> 1:    1   10  some text...  some text, 20190801
> 2:    2   22 some text... , some text, 20190801
> 3:    3   30 some text... ,, some text 20170601
> ```

The approach can be better explained if we look at the intermediate results.

After `melt()`, `long` is

> ```
>     rn variable                   value
>  1:  1       V1                       1
>  2:  2       V1                       2
>  3:  3       V1                       3
>  4:  1       V2                      10
>  5:  2       V2                      22
>  6:  3       V2                      30
>  7:  1       V3 some text...  some text
>  8:  2       V3           some text... 
>  9:  3       V3           some text... 
> 10:  1       V4                        
> 11:  2       V4               some text
> 12:  3       V4                        
> 13:  1       V5                20190801
> 14:  2       V5                        
> 15:  3       V5               some text
> 16:  2       V6                20190801
> 17:  3       V7                20170601
> ```

From this, the lookup table `lut` is created

> ```
>     rn variable  col
>  1:  1       V1 ColA
>  2:  1       V2 ColB
>  3:  1       V3 ColC
>  4:  1       V4 ColC
>  5:  1       V5 ColD
>  6:  2       V1 ColA
>  7:  2       V2 ColB
>  8:  2       V3 ColC
>  9:  2       V4 ColC
> 10:  2       V5 ColC
> 11:  2       V6 ColD
> 12:  3       V1 ColA
> 13:  3       V2 ColB
> 14:  3       V3 ColC
> 15:  3       V4 ColC
> 16:  3       V5 ColC
> 17:  3       V7 ColD
> ```

After the update join and before reshaping back to wide format `long` looks like

> ```
>     rn variable                   value
>  1:  1     ColA                       1
>  2:  2     ColA                       2
>  3:  3     ColA                       3
>  4:  1     ColB                      10
>  5:  2     ColB                      22
>  6:  3     ColB                      30
>  7:  1     ColC some text...  some text
>  8:  2     ColC           some text... 
>  9:  3     ColC           some text... 
> 10:  1     ColC                        
> 11:  2     ColC               some text
> 12:  3     ColC                        
> 13:  1     ColD                20190801
> 14:  2     ColC                        
> 15:  3     ColC               some text
> 16:  2     ColD                20190801
> 17:  3     ColD                20170601
> ```

Now, the data items have been aligned with their respective column names.