# Can't seem to get stringr() just right for mid-string extraction

Tags: r, stringr

I want to extract titles (Mr, Mrs, Miss) from within the `Name` column and import those extracted titles into a new column `Title`. Relevant data looks like this:

```
snippet <- data_frame(Name=c('Braund, Mr. Owen Harris','Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley','Heikkinen, Miss. Laina'),Column=c('blah','blah,'blah'))
```

I've reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56782251/regexp-r-extract-string-between-commas), but I must be missing something.

Here's the best code I could come up with: `snippet <- mutate(snippet, Title = str_extract(snippet $Name, "(?<=,)[^,]*(?=.)")`. This does add the `Title` column, but all values within that column are NA. Where's my error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps - in the column 'Name', there is a space after the `,`, so we use regex lookaround to match non-whitespace characters (`\\S+`) that succeeds after the `,` and space (`(?<=, )`) and precedes the `.` (`.` is metacharacter so we escape or else it matches any character)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
snippet <- snippet %>% 
  mutate(Title = str_extract(Name, "(?<=, )\\S+(?=\\.)"))
```

-output

```
snippet
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name                       Column Title
  <chr>                      <chr>  <chr>
1 Braund, Mr. Owen Harris    blah   Mr   
2 Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley blah   Mrs  
3 Heikkinen, Miss. Laina     blah   Miss
```

#### data

```
snippet <- structure(list(Name = c("Braund, Mr. Owen Harris", 
"Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley", 
"Heikkinen, Miss. Laina"), Column = c("blah", "blah", "blah")), 
class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: That works. Thank you, @akrun! Thanks especially for the helpful explanation.